# Query Todays record in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq

How do i only get todays record in my EF below. I tried below but no luck:

```
 List<VacancyBasket> VacancyBasket = bModel.VacancyBaskets
                      .Where(b => b.BasketID == teacherGuid && b.Created == DateTime.Now)
                      .ToList();
```

I am getting Exception:

> The specified type member 'Date' is not supported in LINQ to Entities.
>   Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties
>   are supported.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to cast to `DateTime` like this

```
var todaysDate = new DateTime(DateTime.Today.Year, DateTime.Today.Month,  DateTime.Today.Day);
```

Now pass it in filter

```
List<VacancyBasket> VacancyBasket = bModel.VacancyBaskets
                  .Where(b => b.BasketID == teacherGuid && b.Created == todaysDate)
                  .ToList();
```

Otherwise you get today's date first.

```
DateTime today = DateTime.Now.Date;
```

Then achieve it like this:

```
List<VacancyBasket> VacancyBasket = bModel.VacancyBaskets
                  .Where(b => b.BasketID == teacherGuid && (b.Created.Value.Year == today.Year &&  b.Created.Value.Month == today.Month && b.Created.Value.Day== today.Day))
                  .ToList();
```

Comment: var todaysDate = DateTime.Today is simpler

Answer (score 3):

Although other answers are correct, you can avoid splitting date by converting your statement into a query instead as following:
First, add the System.Data.Entity namespace onto your class:

```
Using System.Data.Entity;
```

And use the DbFunctions.TruncateTime to cut the time part off, so you can compare between the exact two dates (Today and the VacancyBaskets.Create values):

```
var myCollection = from b in bModel.VacancyBaskets where
    DbFunctions.TruncateTime(b.Created) == DbFunctions.TruncateTime(DateTime.Now) && b.BasketID == teacherGuid
                                           select new {*YOUR SELECTION GOES HERE*};
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use a Date method inside a LINQ statement.  You need to save the date into a DateTime variable and use the variable in your LINQ statement.

Answer (score -1):

You could also use

```
List<VacancyBasket> VacancyBasket = bModel.VacancyBaskets
                  .Where(b => b.BasketID == teacherGuid && b.Created.Day == DateTime.Now.Day)
                  .ToList();
```

Answer (score -1):

If your Created column is a DateTime variable you can do this

```
List<VacancyBasket> VacancyBasket = bModel.VacancyBaskets
                  .Where(b => (b.BasketID == teacherGuid && b.Created.Value.Day == DateTime.Now.Day ) )
                  .ToList();
```